# DevicePolicyManager wipeData not wiping out Email settings

Tags: android, security, device-manager, mdm

I have a device management app that uses the DevicePolicyManager methods. On a specific trigger, I invoked the wipeData method with flag = 0 (its a 2.2 HTC incredible). The device rebooted and wiped all device data (not sd card) along with any configured google accounts (listed under Settings -> Accounts & Sync). However, I was surprised to see that I was still able to receive/send my company emails from the Email app. I had to manually go to the email app click on settings and delete my account.
Any idea if anything is wrong with this. I though being able to wipeData is one of the security measures for an enterprise. And if still one is able to access enterprise email after a remote wipe then it becomes pointless ! I'm absolutely stunned.
Just to be sure, before posting this, I re-ran the whole procedure. Configured my Exchange ActiveSync account, installed my device management app and triggered the wipeData function. On reboot and "data wipe", I find that the configured account doesn't show up in the Accounts & Sync but in the Email app it is still configured and I'm able to send receive messages.

Again, this is happening on my HTC Droid Incredible (Verizon). I havent' yet tested it on any other device. If I get a change to test, I'll update.

**EDIT:**
I tested this on the Droid Pro as well as the HTC Evo. Both are getting wiped cleanly. So Seems that this issue is specific to HTC Incredible. The one I have is running Android 2.2 and the HTC kernel version is : 2.6.32.15-g5e1ad8b htc-kernel@and18-2#1

Answer (score 1):

I think the email is stored on the sdcard for the HTC. the wipe does not clear the SD card and the email is still there when the phone comes back up.